# SEO: Should my homepage be a blog page?

Tags: seo, blog, homepage

From an SEO point of view, should my homepage be my posts page?

We run a business and we have a website that details our services, our prices, our office, it has a who we are page etc... It also has a posts page, in which we highlight some important news from our industry (but not necessarily otherwise related to us) on a weekly basis.

Then we started wondering whether we should have this page as our starting page. From an SEO point of view, is it sensible? After all, the chances that there are no matches between website title and the content from the blog posts, is likely. Also, Wordpress here only generates h2 tags for the blog title, no h1.

Is it then better to create a static page as the homepage, and have a 'news' page somewhere else?

Comment: This is really impossible to say without seeing your site specifically. Anything offered as an answer here would be an opinion devoid of enough facts to really be of any value. Sorry. It all depends on the content and the value of the content and how it can relate to a purpose or effect user perception and/or satisfaction. Only you can answer this question really. That is, unless we too can see your content. Then we would have all of the facts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you described your posts are not so important and relevant for user who first visit your website to appear as the homepage so I would personally recommend to create a static page that contain information of the business and if you want you can include a widget to display links to your recent blog posts.

Static page will be a better choise from SEO prespective because you can have long text that will contain your target keywords or the name of your business.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any difference between a static website or a Wordpress site in terms of SEO. Google generally treats all web pages same. In a case where your blog title is a `h2` tag, you could change it manually.

Google and other pro webmaster always suggest that you optimize the content which bring the most leads/sales to your business which should be your homepage. It is also good in terms of SEO, because it will pass the most pagerank(Juicyrank) to homepage, since your homepage will always be linked from other navigation menus.

Wordpress has many functionality, so you can display your main service at homepage, and blog posts in sub directory like /blog/ . If you go with a static site, then you need to create a RSS feed widget to fetch recent blog posts, which I don't think is a good idea.

You could ask for more help at the [Wordpress Stack Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

From SEO point of view - conversion is also very important. So using your posts page may not be good idea.

> Is it then better to create a static page as the homepage, and have a
>   'news' page somewhere else?

No. Now a days people are using  different platforms to build their websites. Content could be served as static or dynamic. Ranking factors may not depend much on this but the speed. Just make sure the pages are fast enough.

Comment: I think you have a good idea here, but this answer is so short that it isn't high quality.   Can you add details or links to references?